# Console Application crashes remotely but works locally

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, console, console-application, remote-debugging

I have a console application in c#, .Net which I am currently using as a scheduled job.
The idea of this scheduled job is to fetch data and update data.

My solution contains the following:

1. **Web (Mvc)**
2. **Contract (models etc)**
3. **Datalayer (Database)**
4. **Api**
5. **Console Application**

**My issue:**

When I am running my Console application I am refering to a dll from **1 Web(mvc)**. Everything looks good when I am doing this locally, 
but when I zip the catalog, drag this to my remote server and try to run it, I get the following exception:

> Input string was not in a correct format in double.Parse

Basically these lines of code does not run properly on my remote server:

```
var weapons = new Weapons();

userWeapon = weapons.Where(x => x.WeaponId==  userWeapons.WeaponId).FirstOrDefault();
 var parsedValue = Convert.ToDouble(userWeapon.damage);
```

I mean, how is this possible? Why do I get this error remotely but not locally?

If you have any ideas on why this is occuring, please let me know.
Cheers!

Comment: Just a rough idea. Parsing strings into DateTime or double may differ on machines with different language settings. Please add the complete stack trace from the exception to your post.

Comment: Add some logging to your console application (if not already) and provide the exact exception you have.

Comment: @rboe Hey, you were right, the issue was the CultureInfo which I did not specify in my code.. The server I am using for test is in another language..
Thank you!